# Google Chrome Force Ignore Cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fetch, cache-control

How do I force Google Chrome to ignore data stored in its cache?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-store, no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: If it's a specific set of files, you can append variables onto them with unique IDs (e.g. dynamicimage.jpg?dyn=23495628476923, where the number is random or modtime based). Otherwise you should not rely on the user to fulfil anything, and work under the assumption that they'll do the opposite of what you want unless you give them no other choice.